# How to move items between folders Document List?

Tags: document-library, folder, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to move documents between different folders in Document List?

**EDIT**: I mean possible for a sharepoint standard user, not an admin.

For example, suppose that my Document Library has two folders:

```
- Root
  - DocumentA.doc
  - [Project 1 Folder]
     - DocumentB.doc
  - [Project 2 Folder]
     - DocumentC.doc
```

How to move DocumentC.doc in [Project 1 Folder] or DocumentA in [Project 1 Folder]?

**MORE INFO**: I configured mixed Windows and FBA aunthentication, with FBA used my most users.

Answer (score 2):

So not using the Obj Model or code I would simply use Open Explorer view from the Library Ribbon.  I would navigate to the source folder and use the option.  I would than navigate to the target and do the same.  The result should be two different explorer windows representing each Sharepoint folder.  From there it is matter of copying and pasting in the Explorer windows.

Comment: I used mixed Windows and FBA aunthentication, with FBA used my most of users. But when I am logged as FBA administrator and I click "Open with Explorer" it opens a Windows connect form.

Comment: What if "Open with Explorer" is grayed out?  Is there any other method for moving a document once you've uploaded it?  I'd love drag-n-drop, but I'd settle for a simple "Move or copy" option.

Comment: Does the version history move along with the document?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but using

Site Settings > Manage content and structure

you can use this tool to select document, in context menu select "Move document", select target and press OK.

Comment: @Anders I edited my question to better explain my problem. Anyway in Sharepoint Foundation 2010 I didn't found Manage content and structure under Site Settings

Comment: I haven't had a play with 2010 much but did you enable publishing on that particualar site?  I believe that Manage/Content and structure would only be present with Publishing enabled.